# NestJS - how this should be structured?

Tags: node.js, oop, nestjs

Models:
Shop

- Shop A
- Shop B

Orders

- CustomerOrder
- CompanyOrder

1. I create modules for shop & orders
2. How I should implement shops A and B? Extend the shop module class?

Seems odd, since how I can then initialize Shop A, for example?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you don't need to have two shop models because things get confusing overall. The best way to structure this situation is to have one shop model and multiple product models that are going to be part of the shop . Orders can be made by utilizing the CRUD's of the products . Shops for example can have the following parameters in the model :  {name , industry , products , orders }. This is a more structured and scalable solution for the app.

Comment: Shops have different functionalities, so it is crucial to have their own classes for each shop, however, I'm not sure is the best solution to extend the shop module class.